# XNA Texture Stretch Fuzzy

Tags: xna, textures, stretch, fuzzy

If I stretch a texture to a destination rectangle, and I have a simple 1X2 sprite (windows forms button background) XNA stretches the sprite very fuzzy, I get a gradient instead of the bottom part dark and the top one light.
Is there something like a stretchmode so I get the texture stretched as I created it in Photoshop?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338095/super-blurry-textures-xna) question:

```
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.PointWrap;
```